# Send Chrome Desktop Notifications If

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension and i'm trying to have it send desktop notifications when a caller enters the queue, and if they have been waiting for longer then 10 minutes.

```
<tr id="dgrid_0-row-0-tr" class=" ui-state-default dgrid-row dgrid-row-even"><td class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-0 field-AgentCSQStats csqName dgrid-grouprow-cell" role="gridCell" columnid="presentation" title="HelpDesk" pvalue="HelpDesk">HelpDesk</td><td class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-1 field-AgentCSQStats currentWaitingCalls dgrid-grouprow-cell" role="gridCell" columnid="presentation" title="0" pvalue="0">0</td><td class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-Fo00001-2 field-Fo00001 dgrid-grouprow-cell" role="gridCell" columnid="presentation" title="00:00:00" pvalue="00:00:00">00:00:00</td></tr>
```

That is the html source of the location on the page in which I want the extension to monitor.

I believe the best way to do this was to get the xpath of the value I want to monitor.

I wanted to just test out the number of callers in the queue before trying to monitor the time someone has been waiting in the queue. This is what i've came up with...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    var callercount = document.evaluate( '//*[@id="dgrid_0-row-0-tr"]/td[2]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
    if(callercount > 1) {
            if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
                Notification.requestPermission();
            else {
                var opt = {
                    type: 'list',
                    title: 'keep burning',
                    message: 'Primary message to display',
                    priority: 1,
                    items: [{ title: '', message: ''}],
                    iconUrl:'../images/icon.png'

                };
                chrome.notifications.create('notify1', opt, function(id) { console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError); });

                //console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError);  for debug
            };
        };
    };
}, 1 * 1000);
```

});

It doesn't appear to be working...

manifest...

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "background",
    "storage",
```

Comment: The first step is always debugging, which you can perform in devtools. The question doesn't make it clear what really happens and where exactly the code runs (content script or background script) and whether callercount > 1 condition is entered. Note, `"notifications"` permission is for [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications). You're using Web Notifications API.

Comment: @wOxxOm Right now it's in content scripts, should this go in background, considering it should be always checking in the background lol... This is the first chrome extension i've ever made so i'm still learnin. Just updated it. This is a help desk call-in dashboard, called Cisco Finessee, I didn't see any errors in the extension or dev tools, so i'll have to add some console logs.

Comment: 1) callercount is `xpathResult`, not the element's numeric value (probably in its textContent property) or the quantity of elements. 2) You can simplify it using document.querySelector or querySelectorAll, 3) chrome.notifications API won't work in a content script. 4) Debug the code in devtools and inspect the variables and the flow, don't guess.

Comment: `SetInterval` doesn't work in chrome extesnion, you have to use alarms to use interval